# How to reload the part of table?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have this table:

[image]

```
 $(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
 var id = $(this).data("id");
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: "client/"+id,
        type: 'delete',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id 
        },
        success: function (response)
        {
          $("#reload_table").load(window.location + " #reload_table");
        }
    });
});
```

Simply after delete first one `test2` everything is good and reload the part of table, but when I go to delete `test1` it does not delete it, I have to reload the whole page then delete it!

I'm use this for reload the table but it reload for just one time!:

```
$("#reload_table").load(window.location + " #reload_table");
```

How can I make it reload table ?

> I'm not using any library like datatable etc, it just simple bootstrap table.

Comment: Why don't delete the row <tr> using js or jQuery instead of reloading the whole page. It is a bad UX.

Comment: does each table row have a unique id? `<tr row="row_1">...`

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI could you pls explain more?

Comment: @AngadDubey No, it does not!

Comment: @Ahmed check the  answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative : Remove tr after ajax success**

```
@forelse($users as $user)
    //...
    <tr id="{{ $user->id }}">...</tr>
    //...
@empty
    <p>No data Available</p>
@endforelse

//js

$(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
 var id = $(this).data("id");
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: "client/"+id,
        type: 'delete',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id 
        },
        success: function (response)
        {
          $('#'+id).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Foued Do you have couples mins in private? I have another question pls.

Comment: Join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206601/how-to-reload-the-part-of-table

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding the event to an element inside the table row, you should be able to simply delete the table row by finding the closest `tr` to that element:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```